# Does a hole have a spin? If yes, how to determine its direction?

Tags: solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

It is easy to understand that a hole is opposite to an electron in semiconductors. However electrons have spins, up and down, does hole have a spin?

Furthermore, if a hole has its spin, how to determine the direction of spin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do electron holes have spin, and how do they interact with "real" particles / vice versa?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/432044/)